# How to get the client's IP address in Roda?

Tags: ruby, roda

I'm using Roda, and I need to get the client's IP address from the http request. In Sinatra, I think this would be:

```
request.ip
```

Is there an equivalent method in Roda?

Comment: Does the documentation say anything helpful?

Comment: No, I searched it. Maybe I overlooked something, but I don't think so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That exact code should work in Roda.  It's not mentioned explicitly in Roda's documentation, but Roda::RodaRequest is a subclass of Rack::Request, and Rack::Request#ip returns the client's IP.

Comment: Oh wow, now I feel stupid for not trying that. Thanks, Jeremy!

Comment: @jeremy_evans  does this mean that request.ip is `request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']`? Does request.ip also return proxied ip addresses found using `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`? Thanks!

Comment: @jeremy_evans can somehow start to delegate and let the community help you with documentation.

Comment: @AndrewZhuk pull requests for Roda's documentation are always welcome. And request.ip comes from Rack, so the implementation will depend on the rack version in use.